# Suggestions to get Blogger blogID

Tags: javascript, jquery, blogger

**note:** that's my first time to Build Blogger Widgets

First : Blogger blogID major in any Blog source , Is it?

By Googling, most references refer to get blogID by url (from Browser header) after loging to your acount panel `But` no ways or Suggestions to get Blogger id

when you see alot of blog source there is major lines have blogID

```
<link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='https://www.blogger.com/dyn-css/authorization.css?targetBlogID=123456789&zx=xxxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxx-xxddcx' />
```

or

```
<meta content='123456789' itemprop='blogId'/>
```

and more other lines accessible by jQuery for example

```
//extract blog id 123456789
$("meta[itemprop='blogId']").attr('content');
```

Is there another way to get by Blogger API or ..

Answer (score 0):

It's simple: use the `data:blog.blogId`.

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide some explanation for why it does so.

Comment: how to embed <data:blog.blogId> in javascript .. there is an example with alert();

Comment: `alert('<data:blog.blogId/>')`